# Will a small bush growing inches from a mature sugar maple harm it?

Tags: tree-care

I have a mature sugar maple, about 3 feet in diameter, 30-40 ft high. There is a small woody, evergreen, bush growing right next to the tree, inches from it. It is starting to cover the base of the tree. I always feel it will compete with the tree and perhaps strangle the roots. Should I cut down the bush? Thanks!

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you add a  photo of this bush please - hard to answer if we don't know what it is

Comment: @Bamboo added photos. Thanks for taking a look!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shrub growing there is an Abies of some variety - these are evergreen and most get pretty large, so it is far too close to the maple tree. However, judging by its size, it looks like it's been there a while and will therefore be  difficult to remove without damaging the roots of the maple, but you can try,  carefully. Ensure the soil is nice and moist first.

Comment: Thank you! Could I just saw it off at the lowest point without trying to extract its roots?

Comment: Yes you can; many conifers (but not all) don't regrow once they're cut to the ground, so just keep a watch after you've done it to make sure there's no regrowth.

Comment: Will do. I ran into a funny snag yesterday - I discovered that the shrub is growing into the wire fence! The main trunk _looks_ like the fence is going right through the middle. I guess it grew through the holes in the fence and got thicker. Anyhow, I couldn't saw through the base because of the fence. Will try a drill today to make holes at different angles and then try and sever the top from the root system.

Comment: Trees will do that - over time, the trunk will absorb/grow round an obstruction...